# DISM fails to install MSMQ HTTP with 0x800f0922

Tags: msmq, dism

Trying to install Windows Feature `MSMQ-HTTP` via DISM

`DISM /NoRestart /ONLINE /Enable-Feature /All  /FeatureName:MSMQ-HTTP`

fails with

> Error: 0x800f0922
>
> DISM failed. No operation was performed. For more information, review
>   the log file.
>
> The DISM log file can be found at C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After checking the above mentioned `dism.log` and the `%WINDIR%\logs\CBS\cbs.log`, I realised the MSMQ-HTTP install tries to bind an MSMQ application to the default website

Excerpt from `cbs.log`:

> ERROR "Installation of the MSMQ HTTP Support Subcomponent"
>
> ERROR "The full path to the Message Queuing IIS extension is /."
>
> ERROR "Creating a new Message Queuing IIS extension"
>
> ERROR "Starting the default web server"
>
> ERROR "The changes for the IIS extension have been committed."
>
> ERROR "The default Web server started."
>
> ERROR "Creating the msmq web directory"

The problem was that I had deleted the `Default Web Site` in my zeal to start from a clean slate.
Adding the `Default Web Site` back to IIS allowed the MSMQ-HTTP feature to install successfully.

Comment: http://geekswithblogs.net/Plumbersmate/archive/2010/09/09/unable-to-install-msmq-http-support---0x80070003.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Kindly create a new site with siteId = 1 and try to install MSMQ again. You can change the default website ID to 1 as well.

[IIS siteid = 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilQmP.png)